# How to create phtml file to edit home page?

Tags: magento2, phtml

I have phtml file at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/template/content.phtml

**How can I make it to change homepage?**

I have `module.xml` file and `registration.php` file as well. Module is installed.

I suppose that I have to make Block and Controller, but can't get it right.

In wich directories and what files I should make that content.phtml file could make changes to homepage?

Comment: I've given answer and if you require any other information. Please ping here.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order display simple content in home page it doesn't require **Block** or **Controller** instead you follow these steps to display content in home page.

Firstly, you need to change **template** to **templates**.

then

> Add cms_index_index.xml in vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

then add the following code to the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                     
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="vendor_module::content.phtml"></block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

and you can locate your content to specific place in home page by adding these parameters to block element.

> you may use before="before.body.end" or after="before.body.start or after.body.start" etc..,

If you want to display any dynamic content which loads from database then you require block to load data.

Hope this helps.
Peace :)

Comment: Thank's!!! It really helped!

Comment: upvoted ;) But you are missing the closing tag </page>